# Parse color from git log

Tags: git, parsing, shell

I can see the text based graph running the command : `git log --graph --source`.

Is there a way to format the output so that I would be able to parse the color of the branch at any particular line? I played around with --pretty-format, but can't get anywhere with it.

So for example, if the current branch line is red, it would have some sort of an identifier along with it to tell me it's a red line.

Edit: I'm also using Node.js. It is not capable of displaying multiple ANSI color codes in a single line.

Edit: The purpose of this task is to be able to reconstruct the console output in my own application and render it through HTML. I have found an alternative solution for this task in my answer.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? There might be a better way.

Comment: I'm trying to output the text based graph generated by git and make my own representation of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a small script that job for the task that I asked about.

gitgraph.js: http://bluef.github.com/gitgraph.js/

convert git log --graph to image by using HTML5 canvas

Comment: Not completely sure, but it looks like this doesn't parse colors, it just assigns them arbitrarily. Which is exactly what I said.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the colors are just assigned arbitrarily. Every time there's a merge point, two (or more) colored lines come together to form a different colored line. So given that, why do you care about the color at all?

If you're trying to use the color to recreate the output in some other format and you don't want to implement your own color-coding routine, you could throw in `--color=always` and then parse out the [ANSI color codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors) from the output.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I forgot to mention that I'm parsing it with Node.js, which doesn't support ANSI color codes directly.

Comment: @StanislavPalatnik: What do you mean "doesn't support ANSI color codes directly"? Node.js is a language. I have no idea what you could possibly mean when you're talking about supporting ANSI color codes. Unless you're outputting to a terminal, _nothing_ "supports" ANSI color codes. But they're just character sequences and you can parse them out however you want.

Comment: I admit that was ambiguous, but your rant wasn't needed either. Yes, I'm outputting to a terminal, and outputting ANSI color codes to a terminal through Node.js is not supported. You have no idea? You seem to have guessed the concept pretty well.

Comment: @StanislavPalatnik: I assumed you didn't mean what you apparently did, because what you're claiming doesn't make sense. How can Node.js not "support" outputting ANSI color codes to a terminal? They're just characters, and it outputs characters. And in fact I just tested, and it works perfectly fine. `console.log("\33[31mthis prints red\33[m")`. And indeed it prints red.

Comment: If you give it color codes directly in a log, then I can see it working. However, it will not work if there's output from a regular program. For example, there are plugins that attempt to solve this issue (https://github.com/loopj/commonjs-ansi-color). I haven't been able to get it to display color from say, a git log --graph command.

Comment: @StanislavPalatnik: You seem to be extremely confused. The program you linked just gives you simple wrapper functions to emit ANSI color codes. There is absolutely nothing special about node.js and either processing or emitting ANSI color codes.